# Cantor's diagonal argument and ZF

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Cantor's diagonalization construction, on a certain view, furnishes functions 
$$d_X:{\rm Injections}(X,P(X))\rightarrow P(X)$$ 
that satisfy $\forall X\forall i\ \ d_X(i)\not\in i(X)$

In ZF, can one prove the existence of such functions with the added requirement
that $d_X(i)$ actually depends only on the image $i(X)$?

Comment: I suspect ZF doesn't even prove the existence of such a map in the case $X=\mathbb{N}$; see Joel David Hamkins' answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47185/why-is-there-no-borel-function-mapping-every-countable-set-of-reals-outside-itsel. I don't think that answer answers this question, but it does make me suspect that in the smallest nontrivial case we've already gotten beyond ZF.

Comment: Different but related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47185/why-is-there-no-borel-function-mapping-every-countable-set-of-reals-outside-itsel

Comment: @Joel: beat you to it!

Comment: Noah, I see you and I were thinking alike!  But that question was about Borel maps, and this question is more inclusive. 

Comment: Yes, I put in my comment that I don't think that answer solves this question; still, it does make me suspect that ZF is already not enough for $X=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: David, Cantor's argument does not use that $i$ is *injective*, for we can diagonalize against any countable enumeration of reals, even if there are repetitions. Was there a reason you add that restriction?

Comment: Hi Joel...Here's what I was originally thinking about (this may become it's own question).  ZFC makes cardinals well-ordered. Thus, ($\ast$) given sets $S_1 \supset S_2 \supset \cdots$ there must exist $n$ and a surjection $p:S_{n+1} \rightarrow S_n$.  Surely ($\ast$) fails in ZF; I wonder how close one can come.  One idea: from an effective guarantee that every injection $h:S{n+1} \rightarrow S_n$ misses an element of $S_n$ implemented by a function $d_n:{\rm Injections}(S_{n+1},S_n)\rightarrow S_n$ such that $d_n(i)\not\in i(S_{n+1})$,try to derive a contradiction.  Cantor's proof inspires .

Comment: ...this condition.  You're right...Cantor's proof gives more, but I wanted to keep the effective burden as light as possible.  If in addition $d_n(i)$ depends only on the image of $i$, then an argument along the lines of Ricky Demer's leads to a contradiction (because one gets a nested sub family with a well-ordering).  I don't see how to get a contradiction dropping the depends-only-on-image condition, even if one requires witnesses of non-surjectively for all functions, not just injections.

So naturally I wondered if any variation on Cantor could meet my side condition.

Comment: David, it is actually unknown whether or not the well-foundedness of cardinals is equivalent to the axiom of choice. All we know that the cardinals can get very wild, including infinite decreasing sequences. But we yet to know about a model where choice fails and there is no decreasing sequence of cardinals (and even more, decreasing cardinality $\subseteq$ chain of sets); nor we know about a proof that there are no such models.

Comment: Asaf, what interests me is the ambiguity I find, absent AC, around the word "decreasing."  $|A| < |B|$ could mean, minimally, an injection $A\rightarrow B$ (or merely a surjection $B \rightarrow A$), plus the mere absence of any injection $B \rightarrow A$ (or surjection from $A\rightarrow B$).  Instead of these "mere absence" conditions, we might demand a uniform supply of witnesses to the failure of any map (which AC would supply if we had it).  My comment gives a proof that AC does actually preclude infinite decreasing (in one very strong sense) cardinals.  One might seek variations. 

Comment: David, the order defined by surjection is commonly written as $|A|\lt^\ast|B|$. I am actually very interested in the well-foundedness of cardinals without choice; and in fact its relation to the problem of infinite antichains of cardinals (in $\leq^\ast$ more than in $\leq$ to be fair). In the presence of countable choice the two problems are equivalent, but I still don't know what happens when countable choice fails (if there is a D-finite set then there is a decreasing chain, and thus an antichain, but if there is no DF sets, I don't know much yet).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there is such a function then there is an injection from $\omega_1$ to $2^{\omega}$.

(Set $\: X = \omega \:$, $\:$ send the finite ordinals to the corresponding singletons,

then extend to $\omega_1$ with [transfinite recursion](https://planetmath.org/TransfiniteRecursion).)

If there is such a function and the continuum hypothesis holds then $\: 2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1 \:$.

It is [consistent with ZF that the continuum hypothesis holds and](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43861/relationship-between-continuum-hypothesis-and-special-aleph-hypothesis-under-zf/43877#43877) $\: 2^{\aleph_0} \neq \aleph_1 \:$.

Therefore ZF does not prove the existence of such a function.

Comment: A special case of $ZF$ not proving the existence of an injection $\omega_1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$: I believe that $ZF+AD$ (maybe I mean $ZF+AD+DC$?) in fact proves that there is no such injection. To be fair, this does bump the consistency strength up past that of $ZF$, which I think is unnecessary.

Comment: That's why I continued hunting after I found the link that you posted in your first comment.

Comment: Very       nice.

Comment: Noah, a much simpler case where ZF does not prove there is an injection is Solovay's model, and in that model CH holds. Of course this too requires a bump in consistency, but Truss' model shows it is possible to have without inaccessible cardinals if we are willing to have $\omega_1$ singular. If you *only* want the prove there is no injection then it's easiest to do with the Feferman-Levy construction in which the continuum is a countable union of countable sets, one can show that $\omega_1$ does not inject into the real numbers in the Feferman-Levy model.

Answer (score 7):

Joel David Hamkins, Asaf Karagila and I have made some progress characterizing which sets have such a function. <strike>There is still one open case left, but Joel's conjecture holds so far.</strike>

Let $[Y]^{X}$ denote the set of all $A \subseteq Y$ such that $A \approx X$. The question is to characterize the sets $X$ for which there is a function $d:[\mathcal{P}(X)]^{X}\to\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $d(A) \notin A$ for all $A \in [\mathcal{P}(X)]^X$. We will instead try to answer the more general question when there is such a function $d:[Y]^X\to Y$ for arbitrary sets $X, Y$ with $X \preceq Y$. (If $X \npreceq Y$ then $[Y]^X = \varnothing$ and the question is not interesting.) An obviously necessary condition is that $\newcommand{\napprox}{\not\approx}X \napprox Y$ but this is not sufficient as Ricky illustrated. Joel conjectured that such a function exists if and only if $\aleph(X) \preceq Y$, where $\aleph(X)$ is the Hartog number of $X$, the smallest ordinal that does not inject into $X$. We will show that this conjecture is true for all Dedekind infinite sets $X$ (i.e. when $\aleph_0 \preceq X$). Since the statement is obviously true when $X \prec \aleph_0$, the only remaining case is when $X$ is infinite but Dedekind finite (i.e. when $n \prec X$ for every $n \prec \aleph_0$ but $\aleph_0 \npreceq X$).

If there is an injection $f:\aleph(X)\to Y$, then there is such a $d:[Y]^X\to Y$ can be defined as $d(A) = f(\alpha_0)$ where $\alpha_0 = \min\lbrace \alpha \lt \aleph(X) : f(\alpha) \notin A\rbrace$. This last set is always nonempty otherwise composing $f:\aleph(X)\to A$ with a bijection from $A$ onto $X$ contradicts the fact that $\aleph(X) \npreceq X$.

For the converse, the hope is to define an injection $f:\aleph(X)\to Y$ by transfinite recursion where at each stage $\alpha\lt\aleph(X)$, we choose some $f(\alpha) \notin \lbrace f(\beta) : \beta \lt \alpha \rbrace$. To make these choices we would need a function $\hat{d}:[Y]^{\prec\aleph(X)}\to Y$ such that $\hat{d}(A) \notin A$ for every $$A \in [Y]^{\prec\aleph(X)} \colon= \lbrace Z \subseteq Y : Z \prec \aleph(X)\rbrace.$$ What we are given is a function $d:[Y]^X\to Y$ with $d(A) \notin A$ for every $A \in [Y]^X$. A simple idea is to fix some $A_0 \in [Y]^X$ and define $$\hat{d}(A) = d(A \cup A_0)$$ for all $A \in [Y]^{\prec\aleph(X)}$ but this only makes sense when $A \cup A_0 \approx X$. In general, we only know that $$X \preceq A \cup A_0 \preceq A + X,$$ so this strategy will work provided that $\alpha + X \approx X$ for every $\alpha \lt \aleph(X)$. This last statement holds precisely when $X$ is empty or Dedekind infinite. Indeed, $X \approx 1+X$ already implies that $X$ is Dedekind infinite and then $X \approx \alpha + X$ follows from the fact that $\alpha + \alpha \preceq \max(\aleph_0,|\alpha|)$ for every ordinal $\alpha \lt \aleph(X)$.

---

Asaf Karagila and I have made a little more progress on the case where $X$ and $Y$ are both Dedekind finite. In that case $Y \approx X + Z$ and the complement in $Y$ of any element of $[Y]^X$ has size exactly $Z$ and vice versa. Therefore, the existence of a $d:[Y]^X\to Y$ such that $d(A) \notin A$ for each $A \in [Y]^X$ is precisely equivalent to the existence of a choice function $c:[Y]^Z \to X$. In particular, if $Y \approx X+1$ then there is such a $d:[Y]^X \to Y$ since there clearly is a choice function $c:[Y]^1\to Y$. This does contradict the extension of Joel's conjecture to arbitrary $Y$ but not Joel's original conjecture where $Y = \mathcal{P}(X)$. Unfortunately, we still do not know what happens when $X$ and $Y = \mathcal{P}(X)$ are both infinite but Dedekind finite.

The existence of choice functions $[Y]^Z\to Y$ is a very intricate problem. For example, it is known that the existence of a choice function $[Y]^2\to Y$ is equivalent to the existence of a choice function $[Y]^4\to Y$ but that this does not imply the existence of a choice function $[Y]^3\to Y$! These intricate implications have been examined by John Conway in the article *Effective implications between the "finite" choice axioms* [Cambridge Summer School in Mathematical Logic, Lecture Notes in Mathematics 337 (1973), 439–458. [MR0360275](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=360275), [doi:10.1007/BFb0066784](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0066784)].

Comment: Should that be "...such that $d(A) \not\in A$ for all $A \in [\mathcal{P}(X)]^X$."?

Comment: Great job, François! Will someone kindly prove or refute the conjecture? 

Comment: Joel, I am still trying to wrap my head around the amorphous case. I think I may have to call a specialist. 

Comment: The remaining case is not when $X$ is Dedekind-finite but rather when $Y$ is Dedekind-finite. If $Y$ is Dedekind-infinite then $\aleph(X)\preceq Y$ and we can easily give a solution. Additionally, if $Y=X\cup\{X\}$ then it is also clear what $d$ should be. Beyond these two trivial cases, I can't really say too much.

Comment: (Removing my previous comment correction, obviously if we require $X\prec Y$ and $Y$ is Dedekind-finite then we are requiring that $X$ is Dedekind-finite as well...)

Comment: It's a question of perspective. From my point of view, the case when $X$ is infinite Dedekind-finite is the only remaining case to check for the conjectured equivalence $(\forall Y)[\aleph(X) \preceq Y \leftrightarrow (\exists d:[Y]^X\to Y)(\ldots)]$. From your point of view, the only remaining case is to show that there is no such $d:[Y]^X\to Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ are both infinite but Dedekind finite.

Comment: Well, here is a trivial proof that it fails. Let $X$ be any Dedekind-finite set, and let $Y=X\cup\{X\}$. Then $X\prec Y$, and $d\colon[Y]^X\to Y$ is easily defined by $d(A)$ is the unique member of $Y\setminus A$.

Comment: (I still feel that in the case where $Y=\mathcal P(X)$ this should hold, but that is certainly not the same as any two sets such that $X\prec Y$.)

Comment: Aha! Nice, Asaf! In the case where $X$ and $Y = X + Z$ are Dedekind finite, there is such a $d:[Y]^{X}\to Y$ if and only if there is a choice function $c:[Y]^{Z}\to Y$. This has surely been looked at...

Comment: Not surely, but likely. :-) Either way if $Y$ is amorphous and $Z>1$ you can't make that choice. Perhaps this could be a way of proving Joel's conjecture. 

Comment: After checking, the between finite choice principles $C_n$ is all proved locally and the results transfer to this. For example, if there is a $d:[X+2]^X\to X+2$ then there is also a $d:[X+4]^X\to X+4$ but there is not necessarily a $d:[X+3]^X\to X+3$. The known stuff takes care of $Y=X+n$ for $1 \leq n \lt \aleph_0$. The next interesting case is $Y = X+X$.

Comment: That's a nice and reasonably sounding observation. After this we can do $X\times n$ and then $X\times X$ and so on... :-)

Comment: I don't think it's right to cross off Joel's conjecture because he only conjectured it for the case $Y=\mathcal P(X)$, and we only disproved this for the cases of $Y=X+1$ (in $\sf ZF$) and $Y=X+n$ ($\sf ZF+C_n$). I also think that we may want to try and prove that local version of $C_n$ might hold, e.g. $[X+4]^X\to X+4$ implies $C_4(X)$ (choice from subsets of size $4$ of $X$) or something similar.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to read the article yet, but my understanding is that this is exactly what Conway's "effective implications" are: he characterizes when choice functions for $[X]^{n_1},\dots,[X]^{n_k}$ give a choice function for $[X]^m$, which is much stronger than $C_{n_1} \land \cdots \land C_{n_k} \to C_m$.

Comment: I don't understand your remark on Joel's conjecture. The fact that the extended conjecture is false when $X$ is Dedekind finite and $Y = X+1$ does *not* rule out the original conjecture since he only conjectured it for $Y = \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: My remark about Joel's conjecture is exactly what you said. The post suggests that Joel's conjecture has been refuted by the case of $Y=X+1$, but in fact it is still open. In the other direction suppose that $d\colon[X+n]^X\to X+n$ such that $d(A)\notin A$ exists, we define a choice function on $[X]^n$. Given $a_1\ldots,a_n\in X$ replace them by the $1,\ldots,n$ and you have a subset of size $X$ in $X+n$, apply $d$ to this set and the result must be an element from $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. So we are done. 

Comment: (In the other direction part is a bit out of context, it's the proof that the existence of $d$ for $[X+n]^X\to X+n$ implies a choice function for $[X]^n$, which is what I suggested in a previous comment.)

Comment: I'm still confused. That equivalence is exactly what I wrote in the addendum, so where is the issue?

Comment: Oh. I haven't noticed that! :-) Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

Let me point out that in the case $X=\mathbb{N}$, the assertion seems to be simply equivalent to the existence of an injection $\omega_1\to \mathbb{R}$. Ricky has cleverly proved the forward implication. But conversely, if there is a such an injection of $\omega_1\to\mathbb{R}$, then we can define $d_X(i)$ to be the first real not in $i(X)$.

This idea generalizes to higher well-ordered cardinals as well. If $X=\kappa$, then the existence of a map as you request is equivalent to the existence of an injection $\kappa^+\to P(\kappa)$. Ricky's argument again gives the forward direction, and conversely, if there is an injection $\kappa^+\to P(\kappa)$, then we can let $d_X(i)$ be the first set on the list not in $i(X)$.

Perhaps it is true that for any set $X$, the property on $X$ is equivalent to the assertion that the Hartog number $\aleph(X)$, the first ordinal not embedding in $X$, injects into $P(X)$. The converse direction is the same as above, but it isn't clear to me whether one can push Ricky's argument through for this.

Comment: I backed off my previous general claim about the Hartog number, since I don't see how to push the induction through.

Comment: I think it works when $X + X \cong X$. To make the recursion work, we need a function $g:\mathcal{P}_{\preceq X}(\mathcal{P}(X))\to\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $g(A) \notin A$ for every $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ with $A \preceq X$. What we have is a function $g':\mathcal{P}_{\cong X}(\mathcal{P}(X))\to\mathcal{P}(X)$. But if $X + X \cong X$ then defining $g(A) = g'(A \cup \lbrace\lbrace x\rbrace : x \in X\rbrace)$ works.

Comment: Ah, yes, I think that would overcome the difficulty. I wonder if it is equivalent in general? 

Comment: I have to admit that I still don't fully understand the question (but maybe it's this long day that's beating my mental faculties). In my experience counterexamples to things which work for $X+X\sim X$ would usually fail when we try to apply them for amorphous sets, in this case note that if $X$ is amorphous then $\aleph(X)=\aleph(\mathcal P(X))=\omega$. But beyond this I feel that I cannot be of much help in verifying if that which should hold, holds...

Comment: Asaf, that is a good suggestion for a critical case to check. If $X$ is amorphous, then you point out that $\aleph(X)$ does not inject into $P(X)$. But is there $d_X$ mapping every injective image of $X$ in $P(X)$ to a set that is missed? For amorphous $X$, it would seem that every injection of $X$ into $P(X)$ must be essentially trivial in some way. 

Comment: Hmmm. First thing we can observe is that all but finitely many elements of $X$ are sent to sets of the same cardinality (cardinals below $P(X)$ are linearly ordered of order type $\omega+\omega^*$, maps from amorphous to linearly ordered sets have finite range). So now I claim this, if no set was sent to the empty set then we are done; otherwise not all the singletons are in the range of $i$. Let $x_0$ be the element sent to $\varnothing$; if $\lbrace x_0\rbrace$ is not in the range we are done; otherwise pick $x_1$ to be the preimage of this singleton; and continue by induction [...]

Comment: [...] The induction has to stop at a finite point, otherwise we found a countable sequence. So we have a singleton $\lbrace x_n\rbrace$ which is not in the range of the injection; and we can define this as $d_X(i)$. $$\vphantom{space!}$$ Is this good enough?

Comment: Yes! That shows that amorphous sets refute my suggestion on the Hartog number, since you've proved that they have a $d_X$, but meanwhile $\aleph(X)$ does not inject into $P(X)$, because you said $\aleph(X)=\aleph(P(X))$. 

Comment: That's great! Amorphous sets are the best. :-)

Comment: Joel, so it seems we have established in the comments the following: (1) If $X+X\sim X$ then the existence of $d_X$ is equivalent to $\aleph(X)\leq\mathcal P(X)$; (2) If $X$ is amorphous then $d_X$ exists, but both the assumption and the consequence of (1) fail in this case. So how can we characterize cardinals such that $X+X\gt X$ and still $d_X$ exists? Is there any "nice" characterization for them at all? Maybe it is consistent that $d_X$ exists for all $X$ and choice fails, but maybe it's not...

Comment: Actually, my argument only needs $\alpha+X \cong X$ for every $\alpha < \aleph(X)$. Note that $1+X \cong X$ iff $X$ is Dedekind infinite.

Comment: Francois, it's quite easy to show that if $\omega\leq\alpha\lt\aleph(X)$ then $\alpha+X\sim X$. So in fact your argument works for all Dedekind-infinite sets.

Comment: And I think your argument, Asaf, works for all Dedekind finite $X$. I think this is it! 

Comment: Francois, it seems so! We made quite the complements here! :-D

Comment: Asaf, why don't you post an answer explaining it all?

Comment: OK. Everything seems valid: If $X$ is Dedekind infinite, then there is such a map $d_X$ if and only if $\aleph(X) \preceq \mathcal{P}(X)$; if $X$ is Dedekind finite, then there is such a map $d_X$ regardless.

Comment: I should have said, Asaf or François!

Comment: I vote for Asaf :)

Comment: I am writing one right now. I went to check something in the vast bibles of choice principles. I'll finish my answer in a short time. (Thanks for the vote of confidence!)

Comment: Hang on. I see a problem with my argument. The choice of $d_X(i)$ should be independent of $i$, so if $i_1(X)=i_2(X)$ we should have $d_X(i_1)=d_X(i_2)$. But my construction is very dependent of the choice of $i$.

Comment: That's true. So I shall let hope for my conjecture stay alive!  

Comment: Looks like we're stuck in the Dedekind finite case. Can we do it in the really finite case and generalize?

Comment: Perhaps we can simply refute the existence of $d_X$ when $X$ is Dedekind finite but not finite? And perhaps the truly finite case is subsumed by the well-ordered cardinal case? 

Comment: But there is a $d_X$ when $X$ is Dedekind finite and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ isn't. Hopefully this is the only case.

Comment: Ah, and that case conforms with my conjecture, since $\aleph(X)=\omega$, which injects into $P(X)$ if it isn't Dedekind finite. (I'm sorry, I'm just catching up to you guys here...)