# A jump operator for Borel equivalence relations

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

It is well-known that with respect to Borel reducibility the class of Borel equivalence relations on a standard Borel space does not admit a maximal element. We can use the well-known Friedman-Staley jump (as defined [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47185/why-is-there-no-borel-function-mapping-every-countable-set-of-reals-outside-itse/180739#180739)) to show this.

For any Borel equivalence relation $E$ on a standard Borel space $X$, let $E^{\mathcal{N}}$ be the Borel equivalence relation on $X^{\omega}$ defined by
$(x_n) E^{\mathcal{N}} (y_n) \leftrightarrow \{n \in \omega: x_n E\ y_n\} \in \mathcal{N}$ where $\mathcal{N}$ denotes the cofinite filter on $\omega$. Two sequences are $E^{\mathcal{N}}$-equivalent if and only if their entries are eventually $E$-equivalent.

In his paper "[On the reducibility order between Borel equivalence relations](https://books.google.com/books?id=ILI-byUMJVYC&pg=PA151&dq=on+the+reducibility+order+between&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HhvxVPaBJ8OIsQSp0YKYBA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=on%20the%20reducibility%20order%20between&f=false)", Alain Louveau proves that $E \mapsto E^{\mathcal{N}}$ defines a jump operator, that is $E <_B E^{\mathcal{N}}$, for every Borel $E$ with at least two equivalence classes. I will refer to this jump operator as the Louveau jump.

If we let $E$ be the equality relation $\Delta_{\omega}$ on $\omega$, then the Louveau jump would be Borel bireducible with $E_0$. If we let $E$ be the equality relation $\Delta_{2^{\omega}}$ on $2^{\omega}$, then the Louveau jump would be Borel bireducible with $E_1$.

Recalling the [dichotomy theorems](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/38580/1/421148.pdf) due to [Silver](https://books.google.com/books?id=VfiOZWY282QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=su+gao+invariant+descriptive+set+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uh_xVIGrHZHbsASijICYBQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=theorem%205.4.2&f=false), [Harrington-Kechris-Louveau](https://books.google.com/books?id=VfiOZWY282QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=su+gao+invariant+descriptive+set+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uh_xVIGrHZHbsASijICYBQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=theorem%206.3.1&f=false) and [Kechris-Louveau](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1997-10-01/S0894-0347-97-00221-X/S0894-0347-97-00221-X.pdf), we see that $\Delta_{2^{\omega}}$ is the immediate $\leq_B$-successor to $\Delta_{\omega}$, $E_0$ is the immediate $\leq_B$-successor to $\Delta_{2^{\omega}}$ and $E_1$ is *an* immediate $\leq_B$-successor to $E_0$. (Here, "immediate successor" just means that there is no Borel equivalence relation in between with respect to $\leq_B$.)

Are these examples just coincidences or does this pattern persist? Is there a Borel equivalence relation strictly between $E_1$ and $E_0^{\mathcal{N}}$ with respect to $\leq_B$? More generally, if we keep taking Louveau jumps along these relations, do we get a sequence of Borel equivalence relations that are immediate successors of each other?

Unfortunately, I was not able to find much on this jump operator except the paper I linked above and would appreciate being directed to a reference if this has been studied.